# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in eclipse project

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I know that this is one of the most frequently asked questions, but I've tried everything (or almost everything) and are still at a dead end.

There is an Eclipse project with some SWTBot test cases that fail with java heap space error when I try to run them. In addition, Eclipse also fails with same error after some time of work.

I tried to do the following:
-Set arguments in run configuration like -Xms768m -Xmx1024m
-Set same arguments in eclipse.ini (and also arguments  -XX:PermSize=512m,-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m)
-Set runtime parameters in "Configure java" -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
That was not helpful.

[image: Screenshot]
I also tried to look at memory usage and max heap space was about 268 mb!
Is there any idea how to cure it?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Please provide the version of eclipse using and also which version of java you are using?

If possible increase the increae the allocated memory in the ini file further more and and just make sure that you have restarted the eclipse. Or just restart your machine and try once more

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows the heap size is 256MB. It seems there is no more memory for java to run.
How's the whole physical memory? -XX:PermSize doesn't need to be so much, 128MB or 256MB is enough. And eclipse doesn't need to be allocated too much memory either. -Xms and -Xmx can be the same.